# From my chrome extension background script, wants to check if any other chrome extension popup is focused or not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am having an issue which is related to chrome extension.. in which i want to check if any other chrome extension popup is focused or not (popup which usually we assign on extension icon click). I need to collect the data which extension popup is opened especially the title of the window and extension id.

Comment: There is no extension API for that so you'll have to write an external separate utility that uses the [accessibility API](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility) to read the UI. Your extension can communicate with this utility via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Thanks  @wOxxOm for giving time  & valuable information ... I ll try this also